# Shell script foreach logic... Sending data to google drive with gdrive

Tags: shell

i've made a small shell script to send some backup data to a google drive account... It's working fine, but i need to delete old files from google drive. I'm not good with shell script and i don't know how to finish the code below:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Backing up to local folder
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create

# Sending files to google drive https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive
gdrive sync upload /path/to/backups folderID

# Delete 5 days older backups from local folder
find /path/to/backups/* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;

# Get date fom 5 days ago
DATA=`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00 -d "5 days ago"`
```

The line below list all the files IDs i need to delete:

```
# List files to delete
gdrive list -q "'folderID' in parents and modifiedTime <= '$DATA-03:00'" --no-header | awk '{print $1;}'
```

Now I just need to run

```
gdrive delete <fileID>
```

for each id I listed before.

Can somebody help me with this foreach shell script thing?

Comment: Somebody tried to help me but It didn't work... tried the following ways:
    gdrive list -q "'folderID' in parents and modifiedTime <= '$DATA-03:00'" --no-header | awk {'print $1'} | xargs gdrive delete
and
    gdrive list -q "'folderID' in parents and modifiedTime <= '$DATA-03:00'" --no-header | xargs gdrive delete

Comment: What happens if you replace `xargs gdrive delete` with `xargs echo`?

Comment: with `echo` It lists the fileIDs i need to delete...

Comment: I tried now to do like this:
`gdrive list -q ... | awk {'gdrive delete $1;'}`
But also didn't work: `awk: cmd. line:1: {gdrive delete $1;} awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the files into a variable (mostly for readability):

```
files=$(gdrive list -q ...)
```

Then set the IFS to empty so it strips all whitespace but the newline on each line:

```
IFS= read -r file; do
    printf 'gdrive delete %s\n' "$file"
done  <<EOF
    "$files"
EOF
```

I'm using a `printf` so you can see what the command will look like.

This is basically taken from the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Note that this changes the way bash interprets fields in character strings in your current shell.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help! But it didn't work: 
`backup.sh: 18: backup.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected`

Comment: Thanks again! After some research i changed the code based on your help and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mrmcgreg for the help!

```
files=$(gdrive list -q ... | awk {'print $1'});

IFS="
"
for i in $files
do
    gdrive delete $i
done  <<EOF
    "$files"
EOF
```

Maybe it's not the best solution but it worked:

```
backup.sh 
Deleted '1471727727_gitlab_backup.tar'
Deleted '1471727472_gitlab_backup.tar'
Deleted '1471727308_gitlab_backup.tar'
Deleted '1471724530_gitlab_backup.tar'
Deleted '1471627308_gitlab_backup.tar'
```

:D